# Maximize window in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

tmux shows screen like this:

```
[root@wpc-fc2 init]#                                      |············
                                                          |············
                                                          |············
[0] 0:bash 3:bash*               "vi@wpc-fc2:/etc/init" 21:04 21-Jun-11
```

Window has non-maximum width, attempt to copy text from it leads to "|···" getting in text.

How to fix it and get the tmux window full width?

Comment: If you have an actual console viewing the same screen, then you may be limited to its size.  At least this is how it works in GNU Screen.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

tmux windows are limited to the size of the smallest client viewing any session they are linked to (that is, the window is part of).

This can be changed slightly with the `aggressive-resize` window option which constrains them to the size of the smallest client actually displaying that window.

To get the window back to full size, the best bet is to detach any other clients using that window. Use <kbd>C-b</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to select the clients individually or <kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>**:**</kbd> `attach -d` to detach all others on that session.

Comment: I found out dwm doesn't care, though. I had a tmux session open in the stack, as well as full in another tag. Opened MoC and it ended up crashing because the smaller terminal wasn't large enough for it. Gotta be more careful in the future.

Comment: I use tmux occasionally to teach, only issue was the size. I'm an idiot, that first sentence makes complete sense. Opened two terminals as a test and you can literally resize the windows and see the resize in real time. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

Setting aggressive resize option does indeed solve this issue for me (thanks Bob).  I added the following to my .tmux.conf:

```
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize on
```